# Proof of L'Hospital with power series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, limits-without-lhopital

I'm having a bit of problem with this question. I feel like I have to prove the l'hospital's rule but I don't know where to start especially because I have to use the power series.

Suppose that the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$ converge in some non-trivial interval centered at zero, and consider functions $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$. Prove (without using L'Hospital's Rule!) that if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) = 0$, then

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$

Comment: Posting text as an image is not welcome on this site. Since you are a new user, I typed your question manually, but in future, please, always type your question instead of just posting an image. You don't have to perfectly format it with latex, but at least write it down. If nothing else, it makes the question searchable, both on the site and by outside search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. First note, that 
$$ 0 = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0}\sum_n a_nx^n = a_0 $$
and likewise $b_0 = 0$.

Along the same line of thought, we have
$$ a_1 = \lim_{x\to 0} f'(x), \quad b_1 = \lim_{x\to 0} g'(x) $$
Now 
$$ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n x^n}{\sum_{n\ge 0} b_n x^n}
   = \frac{\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n x^n}{\sum_{n\ge 1} b_n x^n}
   = \frac{\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n+1} x^n}{\sum_{n\ge 0} b_{n+1} x^n} $$
What happens for $x\to 0$ in the last fraction?

Comment: wouldn't the fraction become 0/0?

Comment: @user226550 No, because now, you have $a_1$ as the first element of the numerator, not $a_1\cdot x^1$.

Comment: oh wait yea. my bad

Comment: thank you, I get it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You may observe that, as $x \to 0$,
$$
f(x)=a_1x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nx^n
$$
$$
g(x)=b_1x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}b_nx^n
$$ giving
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{a_1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nx^{n-1}}{b_1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}b_nx^{n-1}} \to \frac{a_1}{b_1}
$$ Similarly, since
$$
f'(x)=a_1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}
$$
$$
g'(x)=b_1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}nb_nx^{n-1}
$$ you get 
$$\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\frac{a_1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}}{b_1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}nb_nx^{n-1}} \to \frac{a_1}{b_1}$$ with $b_1 \neq 0$.

Comment: thank you, I get it now :)

Comment: But what if $b_1 = 0$?

Comment: @zhw. If $b_1=0$ then the OP statement is no more true...

Comment: No, it can still be true: consider  $f(x) =g(x) = x^2$

Comment: No, in general it is true. The real theorem (for the power series case, assuming $f(x),g(x) \to 0$) is this: If $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)/g'(x) = L \in [-\infty,\infty],$ then $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)/g(x) = L.$ That includes the case $b_1=0.$

Comment: @zhw. Ok, I got it! Thanks!

Comment: @zhw. Please feel free to complete my answer with an edit or another answer. Thank you.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thanks. I won't have time for a week! Maybe then ...